# An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am testing my web app on localhost for firebase cloud messaging.
I am running it on a virtual host and I enabled SSL for it, I can see https but it is crossed in red. I searched and tried two methods but none of them are working  
`.\chrome.exe --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://firebase_notification.test`
Also,
`chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost` enable this flag

I am still getting the same error.

> An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script.
>   get-notifications:57 An error occurred while retrieving token.  FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).
>       at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.4/firebase-messaging.js:1:30787